# Retrofit + GET method + www-form-urlencoded in Android

Tags: android, get, retrofit, retrofit2, url-encoding

I am trying to fetch a list from a server. Problem is, Retrofit 2.0 is converting my request to an encoded request which is not acceptable to my server. So I need to remove that automatic encoding from the request. I have tried almost all solutions by putting `encoded = true/false` in the Request but it's not working at all.

Now, the situation is: All things are working good with "POST" Requests. Is there any similar way to do it with a "GET" Call? GET requests giving me "400 Bad Request" due to the encoded URL. The Main Issue with Encoding in GET.

POST call:

**Working POST**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<UserBean> getLogin(@FieldMap Map<String,String> params);
```

**POST ENCODED URL:(working)**

```
https://---.---.com/---/webservice/login?
jhobject=%7B%22data%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22username%5C%22%3A%5C%22abz%40cbv.com%5C%22%2C%5C%22password%5C%22%3A%5C%221234%40567%5C%22%2C%5C%22manufacturername%5C%22%3A%5C%22Android%5C%22%2C%5C%22modelname%5C%22%3A%5C%22XT1068%5C%22%2C%5C%22osversion%5C%22%3A%5C%223.4.42-g0a0ded4%5C%22%2C%5C%22countrycode%5C%22%3A%5C%22in%5C%22%2C%5C%22appversion%5C%22%3A%5C%221.0%5C%22%2C%5C%22imei%5C%22%3A%5C%22353325060286683%5C%22%2C%5C%22appfor%5C%22%3A%5C%22Sony%5C%22%7D%22%2C%22enc%22%3A%220%22%7D
```

**Not Working GET**

```
 @Headers({"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    @GET("getlisting")
    Call<MyBean> getListing(@QueryMap Map<String,String> params);
```

**GET ENCODED URL:(Not working)**

```
    https://---.---.com/---/webservice/getlisting?
 jhobject=%257B%2522data%2522%253A%257B%2522pageno%2522%253A%25221%2522%252C%2522totalpages%2522%253A%25220%2522%252C%2522recordperpages%2522%253A%252210%2522%252C%2522cstatus%2522%253A%25221%2522%252C%2522reportid%2522%253A%252253%2522%257D%252C%2522enc%2522%253A%25220%2522%252C%2522token%2522%253A%252209046d74-c047-4534-be0b-050dadad18b8%257E%257E23717%2522%257D
```

Comment: instead of sending json object try some thing like @GET("maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json")
    Call<NearByPlace> getNearBySearchList(@Query("location") String location, @Query("types") String types, @Query("key") String key, @Query("rankby") String rankby);

Comment: No, its not working in Postman.

Comment: add your get URL

Answer (score 0):

You are doing double encoding

in post

```
jhobject=%7B
```

in get

```
jhobject=%257B
```

Comment: I am aware of that double encoding,But still its not working.

Comment: `@QueryMap (encoded = true) Map<String,String> params` have you tried this

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same problem until I remove this line `@FormUrlEncoded` it seems like GET don't need to be encoded or what I don't understand that part
You may wanna remove this line on your code and try it `@Headers({"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})`

Answer (score -1):

I experienced same problem with GET and retrofit, here is the solution with retrofit

1-  Load URL server :

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("URL")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
service = retrofit.create(CallApiService.class);

2- Load config api :

```
public interface CallApiService {
@GET("URI")
    Call<ResponseBody> getProfessions( @Header("x-req-user-id") String x_req_user_id);
}
```

3- Call api and mapping data:

```
RetrofitLoader retrofitLoader = new RetrofitLoader();
CallApiService service = retrofitLoader.getServiceLoader();
Call<ResponseBody> retrofitCall = service.getProfessions("8");
LOGGER.info("conncet to url  :  GET  " + retrofitCall.request().url());
Response<ResponseBody> response;
try {
    response = retrofitCall.execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful())
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    String responseData = response.body().string();
    LOGGER.info("getProfessions Data : " + responseData);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseData);
        return jsonObject.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error jsonObject : " + e);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return "";
```